# Chrome running HTML code does not show image and URL

Tags: html

I am experimenting with html and I have created a very simple html file containing a call to an image and to a URL.  The relevant HTML code is the following:

```
<html>
     <p>
          In this webpage I will display the image I have on my desktop <br/>
          In case you want more images like that visit Google:  <a href = 'http://Google.com' </a>
    </p>

    <hr/>
        <h2> This is the image section </h2>
        <p> The image is the following:</p>
        <img src = '../sea-pictures-020.jpg'    />
    <hr/>
    <p> Copyright </p>

</html>
```

The image is stored in the same directory as the HTML file.

When I open this HTML file in Chrome neither the URL nor the image appear.

Could you explain it?  Your advice will be appreciated.

Comment: ../sea-pictures-020.jpg means upper directory. Use sea-pictures-020.jpg only if the image in the same directory.

Comment: Better see the corrected code below. Explanation is added.

Comment: I think you must learn basics rather than getting stuck in such simple things, this question will not be helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to show all in one.
Your sample has missing  tag (need closing bracket and also title) and the image src should not be referred with ../ as it means upper directory but you need same directory.

```
 <p>
In this webpage I will display the image I have on my desktop <br/>
In case you want more images like that visit Google:  <a href ="http://Google.com"> URL </a>
</p>

<hr/>
<h2> This is the image section </h2>
<p> The image is the following:</p>
<img src = "sea-pictures-020.jpg"    />
<hr/>
<p> Copyright </p>
</html>
```